# Vite: Building a SASS file as it is written

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vite

I am building a library using Vite/Vue3/Quasar and I would like to export a `quasar-variables.sass` file as it is written without it being compiled or anything. Just straight SASS file that I can import to my other projects.

Is this possible with Vite?

Here is my `vite.config.js`:

```
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { quasar, transformAssetUrls } from '@quasar/vite-plugin';
import eslintPlugin from 'vite-plugin-eslint';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        lib: {
            entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
            name: 'AvvinueClowder',
            fileName: (format) => `avvinue-clowder.${format}.js`,
        },
        rollupOptions: {
            external: ['vue'],
            output: {
                globals: {
                    vue: 'Vue',
                },
            },
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        vue({
            template: { transformAssetUrls },
        }),
        eslintPlugin(),
        quasar({
            sassVariables: 'src/style/_quasar-variables.sass',
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': resolve(__dirname, './src'),
        },
    },
});
```

And part of my `package.json`:

```
    "version": "2.0.9",
    "files": [
        "dist"
    ],
    "main": "./dist/avvinue-clowder.umd.js",
    "module": "./dist/avvinue-clowder.es.js",
    "exports": {
        ".": {
            "import": "./dist/avvinue-clowder.es.js",
            "require": "./dist/avvinue-clowder.umd.js"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview"
    },
```

And this is what gets spit out in the `dist` folder:
[image]

Right now everything gets converted to simple CSS and the variables seem to get lost, which is forcing me to declare multiple variable files in multiple repositories, instead of just importing it from my NPM library I'm creating.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [rollup copy plugin](https://github.com/vladshcherbin/rollup-plugin-copy) to copy your file into dist folder

```js
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy'
plugins: [
    copy({
      targets: [
        { src: 'src/style/_quasar-variables.sass', dest: 'dist/style' }
      ]
    })
  ]
```

**Another way**, you can just add your file to npm by excluding it from `.npmignore` file

```
/src  <- This line prevents uploading the whole src folder to npm
!src/style/_quasar-variables.sass  <- This will add your file to npm package
```

Comment: I wonder if `vite` could do that

Comment: "vite-plugin-static-copy" this worked for me in combination with vite:^3.0.4

Answer (score 3):

For [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#the-public-directory) specifically, its easier if you just create a `/public` folder in your root and add files/assets that shouldn't be altered by the build script.